# C Program not Receiving All Input

Tags: c, redirect, input

I am currently writing a program that is supposed to receive input from a text file and output statistics about the text such as the number of letters, size of words and how often they occur, and how many times each word occurs. However, every time I run the program, it does not read all the text. It only reads the first few words. Here is some sample text:

1
Hello my name is Bob 
I live in Canada

It will only read "Hello my name is". It seems to cut off the last word. I import the text from a file using Input redirection from a text file in the compiler (I have to do it this way).

The number represents how many lines are supposed to be read. What should I do to correct my issue? I am very new to programming so I'm sure it is something basic.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>


#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_LINES 10

void letterAnalysis(char [][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal);
int wordLengthAnalysis(char [][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal, int wordLength);
void wordAnalysis(char [][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal);


int main (void){

    int lineTotal = 0;
    int wordSize = 0;
    char text[lineTotal][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char n[1] = {0};

    fgets(n, 800, stdin);
    lineTotal = n[0] - '0';


    for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){}
        fgets(text[i], MAX_WORD_LENGTH, stdin);
    }

    printf("\n***Letter count analysis***\n");
    letterAnalysis(text, lineTotal);

    printf("\n***Word length analysis***\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH; i++){
        wordSize = wordLengthAnalysis(text, lineTotal, i);
        if (wordSize == 1){
            printf("\n%-2d\tword of length %d", wordSize, i);
        }
        else{
            printf("\n%-2d\twords of length %d", wordSize, i);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n***Word analysis***\n");
    wordAnalysis(text, lineTotal);

    return 0;

}

void letterAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal){

    int alphabet[26] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX_LINE_LENGTH; j++){
            switch(text[i][j]){
                case 'A': case 'a':
                alphabet[0]++;
                break;
                case 'B': case 'b':
                alphabet[1]++;
                break;
                case 'C': case 'c':
                alphabet[2]++;
                break;
                case 'D': case 'd':
                alphabet[3]++;
                break;
                case 'E': case 'e':
                alphabet[4]++;
                break;
                case 'F': case 'f':
                alphabet[5]++;
                break;
                case 'G': case 'g':
                alphabet[6]++;
                break;
                case 'H': case 'h':
                alphabet[7]++;
                break;
                case 'I': case 'i':
                alphabet[8]++;
                break;
                case 'J': case 'j':
                alphabet[9]++;
                break;
                case 'K': case 'k':
                alphabet[10]++;
                break;
                case 'L': case 'l':
                alphabet[11]++;
                break;
                case 'M': case 'm':
                alphabet[12]++;
                break;
                case 'N': case 'n':
                alphabet[13]++;
                break;
                case 'O': case 'o':
                alphabet[14]++;
                break;
                case 'P': case 'p':
                alphabet[15]++;
                break;
                case 'Q': case 'q':
                alphabet[16]++;
                break;
                case 'R': case 'r':
                alphabet[17]++;
                break;
                case 'S': case 's':
                alphabet[18]++;
                break;
                case 'T': case 't':
                alphabet[19]++;
                break;
                case 'U': case 'u':
                alphabet[20]++;
                break;
                case 'V': case 'v':
                alphabet[21]++;
                break;
                case 'W': case 'w':
                alphabet[22]++;
                break;
                case 'X': case 'x':
                alphabet[23]++;
                break;
                case 'Y': case 'y':
                alphabet[24]++;
                break;
                case 'Z': case 'z':
                alphabet[25]++;
                default: break;
            }       
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
        printf("%c: \t%d\n", ('a' + i), alphabet[i]);;
    }
}

int wordLengthAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal, int wordLength){

    int sentenceLength;
    int counter, wordSize = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        sentenceLength = strlen(&text[i][0]);
        for(int j = 0; j < sentenceLength + 2; j++){
            if(text[i][j] == ' '){
                if(counter == wordLength){
                    ++wordSize;
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else{
                counter = 0;
                }
            }
            else{
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return wordSize;
}

void wordAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal){

    char maxWords[800];
    char word[MAX_LINE_LENGTH], word2[MAX_WORD_LENGTH], *ptrText, *ptrTextCounter;
    int counter, textCounter = 0;
    int sentenceLength, wordTracker;
    int lineFlag;

    for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        ptrText = &text[i][0];
        sentenceLength = strlen(ptrText);
        counter = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < sentenceLength + 1; j++){
            wordTracker = 1;

            if (text[i][j] == ' ' ){
                if (counter != 0){
                    sprintf(word, "%.*s", counter, ptrText);
                    ptrTextCounter = &text[i][j+1];
                    lineFlag = j;

                if(strstr(maxWords, word) == NULL){
                    for (int k = i; k < lineTotal; k++){
                        textCounter = 0;

                        if (lineFlag == j){
                            ptrTextCounter = &text[i][j+1];
                        }
                        else{
                            lineFlag = 0;
                            ptrTextCounter = &text[i][j+1];
                        }

                        for ( ; lineFlag < sentenceLength; lineFlag++){
                            if(text[k][lineFlag] == ' '){
                                if (textCounter != 0){
                                    if(textCounter == counter){
                                        sprintf(word2, "%.*s", textCounter, ptrTextCounter);
                                            if(strcmp(word, word2) == 0){
                                                wordTracker++;
                                            }
                                    }
                                    ptrTextCounter = &text[k][lineFlag];
                                    textCounter = 0;
                                }
                                else{
                                    ptrTextCounter = &text[k][lineFlag+1];
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                textCounter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(wordTracker == 1){
                        printf("\n\"%.*s\"\t\tappeared %d time", counter, ptrText, wordTracker);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("\n\"%.*s\"\t\tappeared %d time", counter, ptrText, wordTracker);
                    }
                }


                strcat(maxWords, word);
                    ptrText = &text[i][j+1];
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else{
                    ptrText = &text[i][j+1];
                }
            }
            else{
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: 1) `int lineTotal = 0; ... char text[lineTotal][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];` ==> `char text[0][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];`.  Moves after `lineTotal` has been determined.

Comment: 2) `char n[1] = {0}; fgets(n, 800, stdin);` : `800` is Invalid size. It does not match the actual size(`1`).

Comment: 3) `for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){}
        fgets(text[i], MAX_WORD_LENGTH, stdin);
    }` --> `for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        fgets(text[i], MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){}
    fgets(text[i], MAX_WORD_LENGTH, stdin);
}
```

This should be MAX_LINE_LENGTH.